# Installing TaskJuggler results in timeout

Tags: installation, ruby, gem

I'm trying to install [TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/). As far as I can tell, I have successfully installed Ruby and Gem.

The command I'm trying to execute and the error message is:

```
C:\...>gem install taskjuggler-3.5.0.gem
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'term-ansicolor' (>= 1.0.7), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
 connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have tried:

- add a firewall rule for `ruby.exe` to allow any traffic to the Internet
- run the command line as Administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downloading the gem from the website (e.g. [term-ansicolor](https://rubygems.org/gems/term-ansicolor)), installing it manually with the `--local` switch, then running the installation script again to get the name of the next missing gem.

I continued that way until I could install TaskJuggler.

Since I also had problems installing Ruby and RubyGem before, I have now started to create a [TaskJuggler Installer for Windows](http://development.wellisolutions.de/taskjuggler-installer-windows/), which comes with all the components and runs them in the correct order.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that free installer.